# Swagger ui using ip and port instead of domain name

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am running a sprinboot application using swagger.
I just followed a tutorial and in principal it works locally just by including springdoc in my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
    <!--<version>1.2.32</version>-->                                                                                                                                                                                 
</dependency>
```

I also changed the default swagger ui path in the application.properties file

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/harri-api.html
```

No further configuration done.

I deployed my application on a server (running on port 7879) on which the swagger ui is available by its domain - harri.de/harri-api.html. But when I want to use my REST-API itself, swagger does not use the domain name harri.de but the servers ip and port.

Maybe someone can give me a hint where and how to configure the behavior of swagger ui. I just want swagger to use the domain name instead of ip:port

Many thanks in advance
Harri E.

Answer (score 3):

Just enable on Nginx the the Host  name:

```
location /openapi/ {
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/openapi/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement a acceptable solution for my problem.
I added OpenAPi configuration as annotation in my main class.
To be more specific, I defined two servers which are than selectable in the swagger ui editor.

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(servers = {@Server(url = "http://127.0.0.1:7879"), @Server(url = "https://harri.de/")})
@SpringBootApplication
public class HarriApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HarriApplication.class, args);
    }
    ...
}
```

The two server are now available in the top dropdown of swagger ui.

**Remark**

That solution works for me but has basic disadvantages. The configuration is done hard coded inside my sources. This is not very flexible. When deploying on a different host, this approach needs rebuilding of the application.

I also tried to provide a yaml configuration file to add the server entries. But that approach did not work. Referencing a yaml config file like:

```
servers: 
  - url: https://harri.de
  - url: http://127.0.0.1:7879
```

Suppresses the generation of my API spec from soource. It does not behave like a extension on the generated specification.